# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had to try to make a code to automate `steamcmd` but it always gives me the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
```

Code:

```
STEAMCMDDOWN="https://steamcdn-a.akamihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz"

STEAMDIR="~/steamcmd"

if [! -d "$STEAMDIR" ]; then
  mkdir "~/steamcmd"
  cd "~/steamcmd"
else
  if [! -f "steamcmd.sh" ]; then
    wget "$STEAMCMDDOWN" 
    tar +xf "steamcmd_linux.tar.gz"
  else
    echo "steamcmd installed" 
  fi 
  exit
fi
```

Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: To get ahead of your next question, don't quote the `~`; there is no literal directory named `~`, and the tilde won't expand if it is quoted. `STEAMDIR=~/steamcmd`. Same goes for the code that creates the directory.

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command (synonym for `test`), so you need to have some space after it:

```
if [ ! -d "$STEAMDIR" ]; then ...
```

Comment: This is a good read: [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Comment: I tried it this is to give the same error